# open winmerge with two documents side by side c#

Tags: c#, winmerge

I am developing a Windows Forms app in c# that will make changes to a document and I want to include a button that will open the before and after in winmerge.

If it is possible, how do I do it?

More Detail:

I want to click a button [Show Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cmiku.png) with the starting file in the textbox.
It should open winmerge and open [this dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqOGp.png) with the original file on the left and updated file on the right.

So far I have:

```
    Process notePad = new Process();
    notePad.StartInfo.FileName = "WinMerge.exe";
    notePad.StartInfo.Arguments = txtIn.Text;
    notePad.Start();
```

The updated file is in the same directory as the input file one level down in a folder called "UPDATED"

Comment: Hi - welcome to SO. Your question is a bit too open ended, making it less likely that someone will be able to help - please provide more specifics: are you looking for details on how to call winmerge from the command line? Perhaps you have a qeustion on how to use Winforms to provide a file editing GUI? Good luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
String leftFilePath = "...";
String rightFilePath = "...";

string exe = "winmergeu.exe";
String args = $@"""{leftFilePath}"" ""{rightFilePath}""";

Process.Start(exe, args);
```